# How to add HTML page snapshot to Facebook share post

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sharing

I have an app running on Ruby on Rails. I am using Facebook API to share posts. Is it possible to add snippet of HTML code into the sharing post? 
For now only text and link to the page are included into the post. But I basically need to add there a part of the actual page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly inject HTML code. Facebook inspects your page and uses raw-text content of it. You can use the Open Graph meta tags to have more control on the information Facebook uses in the stories.

You can read more on it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices

For example, in your `<head>`, you can add the following tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="This will be your article title" />
<meta property="og:description" content=" A detailed description of the piece of content, usually between 2 and 4 sentences. This tag is technically optional, but can improve the rate at which links are read and shared." />
```